# Why i use Vue.config.silent=true,it still print warn info

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

[image]
I use Vue.set(a,4) to trigger a warn to test the vue.config.silent.Why i use Vue.config.silent=true,it still print warn info.

The code is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/11-silent-8rh5e?file=/src/main.js

But when i change the code position.The silent mode come into effect.There is no warn info.

[image]

The Vue source code also to the silent to control whether to print warn info.
[image]

Comment: @Iyashi, no, it is a vue api.not webpack api.

Comment: These aren't warnings, these are errors. You are using it wrong. Here are the Docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set
first of all, you are missing the `target` parameter, which should be a `Vue` instance like a component (`this` inside `mounted()`) an `Object` or an `array`, second, you have to pass a variable **name**, not a variable itself and third you have to pass the `value` to set the variable with given `name` inside `target`

Comment: @Iyashi,When i use Vue.set(1, 'a', 3). It will trigger an warn which can been supress by silent mode. But，it also start will "[Vue warn]".So how can i distinguish "[Vue warn]" which is triggered by error or warn.

Comment: @Iyashi, even i change the syntax to Vue.set(1, "a", 4) as pic show above; the silent mode still can not suppress the warn info.

Comment: Ok, I didnt notice that you were triggering the warn on purpose, forget what I said. I'm sure this is a bug on `Vue`s side. I'm sorry, but I cant help you out there, I never took a deep dive into `Vue`s source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is triggered by codesandbox.The silent=true will come into effect in your project